# How can I make this sound with Sylenth1 or Massive? (FL STUDIO)

Tags: replication

How can I make the bigroom drop sound (pluck) of this track in sylenth or massive?

I know it has some kind of delay effects etc., but I really don't know what kind of waveforms produce this sound..

(drops at 1:50)

Please, help would be really appreciated like how to make it, which waveforms, which settings etc. I am really new to sound designing and would like to learn these kind of things.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I think its a square kind of pluck with distortion. I would make a filtered pluck sound with Sylenth, use distortion and layer it with a sample plugin like alchemy or just FL's sampler. Put a percussive sample that is almost the same, like in Elysium, and be CREATIVE. Use an eq, distortion, delays, reverb or even download some weird plugins(Fracture, Effectrix, Omicide Meloman).

Answer (score 1):

Its made of at least 2 obvious layers.

1. First layer is a FM Pluck with a lot of Reverb to give it space. You will find tutorials on FM Plucks on youtube (search Martin Garrix - Animals tutorials since his Drop sound is a FM Pluck ...)
2. Second Layer some kind of the typical Filtered Supersaw/Square Pluck that every Big Room House uses. The idea is to layer different detuned synths to create a Big Unison sounds over the stereo field. By using the cutoff filters with a typical AD-Envelope to get the Pluck sound. Also vibrate helps to make it more fat. After the filter try different type of Distortion sounds and boost the high end to the point the sound is extremely aggressive. You will find tutorials on this on youtube If you search Big Room House drop

For 2 I would use A layer of Sylenth with a layer of Massive. For 1 I would use Abletons Operator or FM8.

Good Day

PS: And you need to sample Sander van Doorns - Joyenergizer Kick if you want the Drop to sound the same.